# Unable to add a Refinable/Managed-Property for our Yes/No field

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, crawled-property, refinement-panel

I have a site column named Deal of type Yes/No, now i want to add a refinable for this column. so i went to search >> search schema >> managed properties >> search for a refinable of type Text >> then i tried adding a crawl property named `ows_Deal` and a crawl property named `ows_1_BOOL_Deal` as follow:-

[image]

but none of these refinables work inside my refinable web part? any idea? should i create a managed property of type Yes/No instead of relying on the built-in Text type?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever wait at least 24 hours?

If so, it seems the refinablestringNN can only map text type of crawled property.

We can create a new managed property for Yes/No field, but it's not refinable.

Comment: @Hallofiona_MSFT but which crawl propert i should use ? `ows_deal` or `ows_q_BOOL_deal`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ows_Deal` field. Somewhere in the doc it states to not use the other as it is used for a legacy feature for automatically created managed properties.

I would try mapping it to both Text and Integer types and test to see which result works best for you.

Comment: i tried using the `ows_q_BOOL_deal` but insdie the refiner it showed the values as All,1 & 0 ... so not sure if this is how to suppose to work?

Comment: That is. 1=Yes 0=No. Try it with ows_Deal.

Comment: @Matthen yes i know that 1 & 0 represents Yes,No but this is not user friendly, will try the other CP.. thanks

Comment: i tried ows_deal but i also got the refiner as 1 & 0 .. not sure if i can change this?

Comment: You may have to create your own refiner template for it to convert 1/0 to "Yes" and "No".

Comment: can you advice more on this?

Comment: What do you need to know?